# Is it possible to pass in command line variables to a bitbake build?

Tags: build, command-line-arguments, compiler-flags, openembedded, bitbake

I have an OpenEmbedded environment using bitbake to do some builds. I wanted to get something "interactive" going on where bitbake would pause and ask for input then continue with the build but I've found out that's not possible.

Since I can't do that I'm looking for some way to pass in extra flags for the build. Is there any way to pass in flags to a bitbake build sort of like gcc's `-D` option?

ie:

```
bitbake -Dfoo=bar oe-myimage
```

Thus during the build process of `oe-myimage` the variable `foo` will be set to `bar`.

Answer (score 34):

```
bitbake -Dfoo=bar oe-myimage
```

-D flag is not recognized by bitbake. So, using above method will not work. Instead you could specify flags from command line using following steps -

Say you want to export variable foo and expect it be recognized by bitbake.

```
export foo="foobar"
```

You will need to export this and inform bitbake via BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE variable after sourcing oe-init-build-env. This means

```
. oe-init-build-env
export foo="foobar"
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="$BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE foo"
```

This whitelists variable 'foo' for bitbake and thus makes it visible to any recipe and subprocess during the build.

After this you can invoke any bitbake operations using variable foo within bitbake via expressions like -

```
${foo}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the extra variable permanent?
In some configuration files or so?
Or do I need to export the BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE after each system reboot?

Comment: Yes. You only need to set the variable wherever is more convenient for you. e.g. add the 2 export lines above mentioned to oe-init-build-env.

Comment: I am getting the error: 
Variable BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE has been renamed to BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS.
Any idea?

Comment: @EzyHoo Any idea? Really? The error message literally tells you what to do. Just replace `BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE` with `BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS`.

Answer (score 13):

While there is nothing wrong with the other answers bitbake does accept a `--postread` argument as documented [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax). That means that you can write as many bitbake variables as you want to some temporary configuration file and have it read after bitbake.conf by specifying the name of the file on the command-line. For example:

```
bitbake --postread=./extra.conf
```

I personally find this more convenient than dealing with environment variables.

Comment: It seems `--postread` is not the final say on a variable value, i.e., it also can be override...I am not sure if there is a way to give a final value to a variable in the similar way...

Answer (score 7):

you can do:

```
export foo="bar"
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="$BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE foo"
bitbake oe-myimage
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Variable BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE has been renamed to BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

There's also a convenient command-line way to do this, that's described in the bitbake manual using [BB_ORIGENV](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#passing-information-into-the-build-task-environment):

> Sometimes, it is useful to be able to obtain information from the original execution environment. Bitbake saves a copy of the original environment into a special variable named BB_ORIGENV.

To do so, you could read a variable exactly as they suggest (from a Python function):

```
 origenv = d.getVar("BB_ORIGENV", False)
 bar = origenv.getVar("BAR", False)
```

Then, the way to pass that from the command line is simply:

```
BAR=somevalue bitbake myimage
```

Comment: One-line variant: `BAR = "${@d.getVar('BB_ORIGENV').getVar('BAR')}"`

Comment: This is great solution. But unfortunately with latest `bitbake` this is now throwing `"the basehash value changed"` error on execution. The job will still run, but with hash mismatch errors!

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe such a mechanism exists.  But you could do something like

```
"echo "foo = \"bar\"" >local.conf
```

Not sure that will solve your particular problem or not.  Also, there is a mechanism for local site-wide variables: if you have a 'site.conf' file in your home directory under a directory called .oe, bitbake will read that and apply those variables to the global environment for every build.  Maybe that would help?  You didn't specify exactly what problem you are trying to solve, there might be better ways.