# If else statement using external variable in a bitbake file

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, texas-instruments

Hi under my bitbake file I want to stop the execution of certain tasks and want compile function to be executed every time. For this, I have done the following changes.

```
do_compile[nostamp] = "1" 
do_clean[noexec] = "1" 
do_cleanall[noexec] = "1" 
do_cleansstate[noexec] = "1" 
do_fetch[noexec] = "1" 
do_patch[noexec] = "1" 
do_unpack[noexec] = "1"
```

And it worked perfectly fine. I was able to stop the execution of tasks like clean, cleanall, cleansstate, fetch, patch and unpack. Also, I was able to make sure that the compile task runs every time.

However, I want to put some restrictions on the same. I want to make sure that noexec and nostamp on relevant task only applies when **DEVMODE** variable is set to 1. **Psuedo code** as follows.

```
if DEVMODE == 1 then
    do_compile[nostamp] = "1" 
    do_clean[noexec] = "1" 
    do_cleanall[noexec] = "1" 
    do_cleansstate[noexec] = "1" 
    do_fetch[noexec] = "1" 
    do_patch[noexec] = "1" 
    do_unpack[noexec] = "1"
endif
```

How to achieve the same in a bitbake file? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366984/is-it-possible-to-pass-in-command-line-variables-to-a-bitbake-build) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268512/bitbake-conditional-inclusion-of-depends-statement) links but I am not able to craft a working if condition.

NOTE: Am ok using BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE, but am not able to code a working if condition for the bitbake file.

Comment: As I know `if` is not a part of the bitbake syntax, but of bitbake functions. You may create a function with a conditional statement.

Comment: So if not then how can I implement such functionality?

Comment: Usually you have two bb files ... one for the release build and the other for the debug builds.

Comment: @SunnyShukla - try L

Answer (score 1):

Use [python anonymous function](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#anonymous-python-functions) could work for you.

```
python () {
    #add "export DEVMODE=1" under conf/setenv
    #add DEVMODE under BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE variable under conf/setenv

    if d.getVar("DEVMODE", True) == "1":
        d.setVarFlag("do_compile", 'nostamp', "1")
}
```

Or set directly:

```
do_compile[nostamp] = "${@'1' if d.getVar('DEVMODE') == '1' else '0'}"
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, the edited code has worked for me, please accept the edit so that I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @SunnyShukla, d.getVar() doesn't need explict option 'True' right now that it is the default value.