# Excluding yocto meta-layer depending on a variable value

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am playing around with yocto for a personal project. I have a layer called `meta-nightcore` which has several files writen in different languages: bash, Python, C, C++ and several recipes.

Is it possible to exclude the `meta-nightcore` when calling `bitbake <image_name>` when a user defined variable `NIGHTCORE_ENABLED`? This variable is set via shell command before calling `source oe-init-build-env`.

If you have different ideas, can you also share?

Thanks anh Best Regards,
Duy Tran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [pass your environment variable into the build environment](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#passing-information-into-the-build-task-environment) and then use it to conditionally add the extra layer(s).

You'll need to modify your `bblayers.conf` to store a default value for `NIGHTCORE_ENABLED` and to add the extra layer(s) to `BBLAYERS` if it is set to `1`:

```py
NIGHTCORE_ENABLED ?= "0"  # overridden by env if specified in BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE
NIGHTCORE_LAYERS ?= "/path/to/poky/meta-nightcore"

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /path/to/poky/meta \
  /path/to/poky/meta-poky \
  /path/to/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${@bb.utils.contains('NIGHTCORE_ENABLED', '1', '${NIGHTCORE_LAYERS}', '', d)} \
"
```

Then, you need to tell Bitbake to allow your environment variable to be captured into the Bitbake datastore by adding it to `BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE`:

```sh
export NIGHTCORE_ENABLED=1
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="${BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE} NIGHTCORE_ENABLED"
```

You can then run `bitbake <image_name>`.

Because `bblayers.conf` is usually generated when `source oe-init-build-env` is run for the first time, you may wish to [use `TEMPLATECONF` to create a `bblayers.conf.sample` file](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#creating-a-custom-template-configuration-directory) that already includes this extra logic.

There's some related answers here too:

> [Is it possible to pass in command line variables to a bitbake build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366984)

Comment: Hi @Justin, I made it work thanks to your idea. Thank you. :D